# How do I return mocked item only on the x:th call?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have run into a problem using PowerMock where I feel forced to create ugly code if I want to return a mocked item only once.
As an example I have the following code:

```
mockMap = spy(new HashMap());
HashMap<String, String> normalMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String> normalMap2 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String> normalMap3 = new HashMap<>();
whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(normalMap)
    .thenReturn(mockMap)
    .thenReturn(normalMap2)
    .thenReturn(normalMap3);
```

This of course works, but it feels very clunky, especially as I need to create a new hashmap for every new call.

So my question is: is there a way to tell PowerMock that it should stop interfering after a set amount of calls?

**edit:**
After reading the answers, I got the following:

```
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments().thenAnswer(invocation -> {
switch (count.incrementAndGet())
{
        case 1:
            return mockMap;
        default:
            return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
});
```

However it gives me a StackOverFlowError using the following code:

```
describe("test", () -> {
    beforeEach(() -> {
        mockStatic(HashMap.class);
        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
        whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments().thenAnswer(invocation ->
        {
            switch (count.incrementAndGet())
            {
                case 5:
                    return mockMap;
                default:
                    return new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
        });
    });
    it("Crashes on getting a new HashMap", () -> {
        HashMap map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("test", "test");
        HashMap normal = new HashMap<String, String>();
        expect(normal.containsValue("test")).toBeTrue();
    });
});
```

Worth noting is that I don't have a mockStatic(HashMap.class) in my larger tests that get the same errors(which I get rid of if I remove the mockStatic call)

A solution that works(but feels like a workaround) is building on that by editing the default statement into:

```
default:
    normalMap.clear();
    return normalMap;
```

Comment: My question is: why don't you have accessto that hashmap? Is it an *implementation detail* which your test should not know about at all?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle The reason for it is that it is using the hashmap to build headers for an HTTP request. If I where to give access from the testcase then I think that my under test class would break and I don't see any good way around it.

Comment: you can shorten the code like this `.thenReturn(normalMap, mockMap, normalMap2, normalMap3)`; since it takes varargs.

Comment: if you only need mockMap on second call and just a empty hashmap on other calls you can do it like this `.thenReturn(normalMap, mockMap, normalMap)`. after second calls it keeps returning the last item i.e normalMap

Comment: *"it is using the hashmap to build headers for an HTTP request."* - UnitTests verify *public observable behavior*. That means you verify the output and/or communication with dependencies. But a Hashmap usually is a datastructure, not a dependency.

Comment: @pvpkiran I tried that however the problem that I got was that on the second normalMap it already had some entries(i.e I did not get a new HashMap) which broke other parts of the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mockito's `org.mockito.stubbing.Answer`:

```
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<HashMap<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        count.incrementAndGet();
        switch (count.get()) {
            case 1: // first call, return normalMap
                return normalMap;
            case 2: // second call, return mockMap
                return mockMap;
            case 3: // third call, return normalMap2
                return normalMap2;
            default: // forth call (and all calls after that), return normalMap3
                return normalMap3;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that I had to use `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` and declare it as a `final` variable for 2 reasons:

- variables used inside the anonymous class must be final ([because Java defined it that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/7605325))
- if I create a `final int`, I can't do `count++`

**Note**: in this solution, you must also change all `normalMap`'s to be `final`

---

Actually, if all your `normalMap`'s are the same, you can just do:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<HashMap<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        count.incrementAndGet();
        if (count.get() == 2) { // second call
            return mockMap;
        }
        return normalMap; // don't forget to make normalMap "final"
        // or if you prefer: return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
});
```

---

**PS**: as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915930/7605325), instead of using `AtomicInteger`, you can also create an `int` counter inside the anonymous class (it's up to you to choose, as both work):

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<HashMap<String, String>>() {

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        count++;
        if (count == 2) { // second call
            return mockMap;
        }

        return normalMap; // don't forget to make normalMap "final"
        // or if you prefer: return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
});
```

And this also works with the `switch` solution as well.

Comment: I really like that I can logically choose when to return the mock using the thenAnswer function, however I am still getting stuck on it not returning a new object on each normal object. That results in a large switch anyways so I need to write more code than before. So, I would need it to return a empty HashMap on every normal object in order for this to work

Comment: What do you mean by *"not returning a new object on each normal object"*?

Comment: ok, say that I don't want the first two objects to be mocked.
The code that is under test will edit the first HashMap returned by adding entries.

The second time the code under test creates a HashMap, it will get a HashMap containing those entries.

This is if I follow your last example.
If I where to edit it to not return normalMap and instead new HashMap<String, String>(), I get a stackoverflow exception.

one solution that I have found is clearing the normalMap before returning it, but it seems like a workaround

Comment: Could you edit your question and post your test code? Just to check why the stackoverflow exception occurs (my test if very simple and I've got no errors)

Comment: I have made some edits, however I cannot post the test code.

Comment: Well, I'm still not getting any errors (I did a test adding some entries to the hashmaps as you said, but no error occurs). The stackoverflow might be related to something else you're doing with these maps or in some other part of the code. But I can't figure out what it is.. Would you mind posting the stacktrace/error messages?

Comment: I managed to reproduce it with a much smaller test(se my example). However in that example I must use mockStatic to get the overflow exception, which I don't otherwise use.

Comment: I don't think you need to `mockStatic` a `HashMap`, as you're not using any static method of it. Are you using [spectrum](https://github.com/greghaskins/spectrum)?

Comment: I know I don't need it and I don't use it in my real test, however it was atleast a way of reproducing the error without pasting in 50 files. No I am using [oleaster-runner](https://github.com/mscharhag/oleaster/tree/master/oleaster-runner) instead of spectrum

Comment: I'm getting trouble to run your code. How do you combine powermock and oleaster runners together? Sorry, I don't use oleaster very often

Comment: No need to apologize, I am just glad that you are trying to help :)    if you want to use oleaster and powermock you need to provide the following annotations on the test class `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(OleasterRunner.class)`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Maybe I'm using an incompatible version of powermock, I don't know. I'll take a look and see what I can find..

Comment: I could reproduce the error (by changing my powermock's version), but not sure how to fix it. Looking at the stacktrace, I can't know if the problem is in powermock, mockito, oleaster, or the combination of all. Have you tried using old-plain unit tests (without oleaster)? I'd also suggest opening an issue in oleaster github.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [thenReturn](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn(T,%20T...)) with multiple arguments like this:

```
whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(normalMap, mockMap, normalMap2, normalMap3);
```

Or write your own [Answer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/index.html?org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html) like this:

```
whenNew(HashMap.withNoArguments()).doAnswer(new Answer() {
    private int count = 0;

    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        // implement your logic
        // if (count ==0) etc.
    }
});
```